# iOS buttons in overlays fire additional clicks on elements below the overlay

Tags: javascript, css, ios

I am facing a strange problem on iOS devices.

When clicking on buttons/links in an overlaying container, the element below fires also a click event. I have a "filter" button that opens an overlaying div with all the filter options. The closing button on the overlay is located directly over the button, that triggers the overlay. When I click on the close button, the overlay closes, and with a small delay, a click on the filter button is executed again and opens the overlay.

This also happend when I build my mobile menu, where I had a burger button on the top right which opens my mobile menu. The closing button was located where the burger button was. When clicking on the closing button, the click on the burger button is executed again and opens the menu.

I tried to bind a stopImmediatePropagation() to the buttons, but this doesn't work out. This only happens on iOS, Android and Desktop is fine. The functionality of the overlays comes from my used e-commerce system (Shopware 6). It is not only happening with buttons, but with other elements like divs and spans with a functionality to hide/close overlays.

Any ideas how to get rid of this?

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it with fastclick.js
https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Not what is designed for, but fortunately it solved the click issue on iOS.